# Are alpha-ketoglutarate and glutamate involved in all transamination reactions?

Tags: biochemistry, homework, metabolism, amino-acids

Is it true that for all biochemical transamination reactions, that alpha-ketoglutarate and glutamate serve as the amino group acceptor and donor, respectively?

If this is true, then is it safe to assume that alpha-ketoglutarate is necessary for every transamination reaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The major transaminases such as the [aspartate transaminase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspartate_transaminase) and [alanine transaminase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alanine_transaminase) involve the glutamate α-ketoglutarate interconversion. Even the [GABA aminotransferase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-aminobutyrate_transaminase) employs glutamate/α-ketoglutarate. It seems that all transaminases use glutamate/α-ketoglutarate; in fact most of them do.

These are a few that don't:

- [Beta-alanine--pyruvate transaminase.](http://enzyme.expasy.org/EC/2.6.1.18)
- [Tryptophan--phenylpyruvate transaminase.](http://enzyme.expasy.org/EC/2.6.1.28)
- [Pyridoxamine--pyruvate transaminase.](http://enzyme.expasy.org/EC/2.6.1.30)
- [Aminolevulinate aminotransferase.](http://enzyme.expasy.org/EC/2.6.1.43)
- [Serine--pyruvate transaminase.](http://enzyme.expasy.org/EC/2.6.1.51)
- [Aspartate--prephenate aminotransferase.](http://enzyme.expasy.org/EC/2.6.1.78)

And a few more ([see here](http://enzyme.expasy.org/EC/2.6.1.-)). Most of these are present in plants.